# perl : Regex while reading a file

Tags: regex, perl, file

I have an array of files. Each file with few lines of text, out of which I am trying to get few specific strings through regex in perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $myfile (@myFiles) {
    open my $FILE, '<', $myfile or die $!;
    while ( my $line = <$FILE> ) {
        my ( $project, $value1, $value2 ) = <Reg exp>, $line;
        print "Project : $1 \n";
        print "Value1 :  $2 \n";
        print "Value2 :  $3 \n";
    }
    close(FILE);
}
```

*** File Content ***

```
Checking Project foobar
<few more lines of text here>
Good Files excluding rules:     15 -   5%
Bad Files excluding rules:    270 -  95%

<one more line of text here>
Good Files including rules:     15 -   5%
Bad Files including rules:    272 -  95%
<few more lines of text here>
```

*** Desired Output ***

```
 Project:foobar  
 Value1 : Good Files excluding rules:     15 -   5%
          Bad Files excluding rules:    270 -  95%   
 Value2 : Good Files including rules:     15 -   5%
          Bad Files including rules:    272 -  95%
```

Comment: `open my $FILE, '<', $myfile  die $!;;` missing an `or` between `$myfile` and `die`.

Comment: Are these lines in a strict order like `Good/Bad excluding`, then `Good/Bad including` or are they out of order and possibly interlaced? Also, I haven't kept up with Perl much, is this `<Reg exp> ,$line` a new construct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not worth attempting to create a single regex to capture all of your desired values.

Instead just do line by line processing, and create a regex for each type of line that you want to match.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fh = \*DATA;

my $counter = 0;

while (<$fh>) {
    if (/Checking Project (\w+)/) {
        printf "Project:%s\n", $1;

    } elsif (/^Good Files/) {
        printf "Value%-2s: %s", ++$counter, $_;

    } elsif (/^Bad Files/) {
        printf "       : %s", $_;
    }
}

__DATA__
Checking Project foobar
<few more lines of text here>
Good Files excluding rules:     15 -   5%
Bad Files excluding rules:    270 -  95%

<one more line of text here>
Good Files including rules:     15 -   5%
Bad Files including rules:    272 -  95%
<few more lines of text here>
```

Outputs:

```
Project:foobar
Value1 : Good Files excluding rules:     15 -   5%
       : Bad Files excluding rules:    270 -  95%
Value2 : Good Files including rules:     15 -   5%
       : Bad Files including rules:    272 -  95%
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this:

```
(good.*|bad.*)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/nY6vJ2/1)**

[image]

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [54-95] `Good Files excluding rules:     15 -   5%`
MATCH 2
1.  [96-136]    `Bad Files excluding rules:    270 -  95%`
MATCH 3
1.  [167-208]   `Good Files including rules:     15 -   5%`
MATCH 4
1.  [209-249]   `Bad Files including rules:    272 -  95%`
```

Using above regex, you can capture the lines you need. Then you have to add some logic to generate your desired output.